# How do I stop flickering in my transparent Splash screen in Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, transparent, splash-screen

Using a bit of modified code I found on the web for creating a generic Tkinter splash screen, I tried to to create a transparent splash screen kind of thing with a .png. I know this code will only work with Windows and I am fine with that.

However, I notice there is flickering (Canvas area is black before it draws the picture) with the image when it draws on the screen. I don't know very much about it but I suspect it has to do something with the buffering of the image after googling and reading. I also read that canvas supports double buffering so the flickering shouldn't be happening so maybe it's the Top Level widget or something.

In any case is there any fix to this? I'd really like to continue using Tkinter for this and it would be a huge letdown not to be able to get rid of the flickering. Here is the code I am using below.

```py
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

class Splash:
    def __init__(self, root, filename, wait):
        self.__root = root
        #To use .pngs or .jpgs instead of just .bmps and .gifs, PIL is needed
        self.__file = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
        self.__wait = wait + time.clock()

    def __enter__(self):
        # Hide the root while it is built.
        self.__root.withdraw()
        # Create components of splash screen.
        window = Toplevel(self.__root)
        #Set splash window bg to transparent
        window.attributes('-transparent', '#FFFFFE')

        #Set canvas bg to transparent
        canvas = Canvas(window,bg="#FFFFFE")
        splash = self.__file
        # Get the screen's width and height.
        scrW = window.winfo_screenwidth()
        scrH = window.winfo_screenheight()
        # Get the images's width and height.
        imgW = splash.width()
        imgH = splash.height()
        # Compute positioning for splash screen.
        Xpos = (scrW - imgW) // 2
        Ypos = (scrH - imgH) // 2
        # Configure the window showing the logo.
        window.overrideredirect(True)
        window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(Xpos, Ypos))
        # Setup canvas on which image is drawn.
        canvas.configure(width=imgW, height=imgH, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.pack()
        # Show the splash screen on the monitor.
        canvas.create_image(imgW // 2, imgH // 2, image=splash)
        window.update()
        # Save the variables for later cleanup.
        self.__window = window
        self.__canvas = canvas
        self.__splash = splash

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Ensure that required time has passed.
        now = time.clock()
        if now < self.__wait:
            time.sleep(self.__wait - now)
        # Free used resources in reverse order.
        del self.__splash
        self.__canvas.destroy()
        self.__window.destroy()
        # Give control back to the root program.
        self.__root.update_idletasks()
        self.__root.deiconify()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 #thread2 = myLazyDoStuffThread()

 root = Tk()
 with Splash(root,'splash.png',3):
      myprog = ApplyGUIAndOtherThings(root)#,thread2)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `-transparent` did not work for me but `-alpha` could do.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb you should follow is to never put a call to `sleep` in a GUI. It does exactly what it says, it causes your whole application to sleep. This means that the GUI is not able to redraw itself, and is likely the cause of your flicker.

If you want a window to be destroyed after a period of time, use the `after` method. For example:

```
delta = (self.__wait - now) * 1000
self.after(delta, self.close)
```

You'll need to define self.close to destroy the window.

This gives you an opportunity to add a little "fade away" effect if you like. You do this by checking to see if the alpha of the splash screen is below some threshold (say, 10%) and destroy it. If it's not, reduce the alpha by 10% and call the function again in 100 ms.